# HTML, CSS and maybe JQUERY - hide first-child and last-child icons in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a table where one of the  is like this:

```
<td class="acciones" width="20%">
     <span class="btn-group-action">
     <!-- EDITAR -->
     <span data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn-group label-tooltip" data-original-title="Editar" data-html="true" data-placement="left">                                                    
                                                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-default " href="<?php echo base_url('diccionarios/elemento_especifico_diccionario').'/'.$elemento['ELDI_Id'];?>" title="Editar">
                                                        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                                    </a> -->
                                                    <a class="btn btn-default editar_elemento_diccionario" title="Editar">
    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
  </a>
 </span>
<!-- BORRAR -->
<span class="btn-group label-tooltip eliminar_elemento_diccionario" id='<? 
   php echo $elemento['ELDI_Id']; ?>' title="Eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip">
   <a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="material-icons">delete</i> 
   </a>  
</span>  
</span>

 <span class="btn-group-action" style="margin-right:3.46px">
 <!-- BAJAR POSICIÓN -->
 <span data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn-group label-tooltip" data-original- 
   title="Bajar posición" data-html="true" data-placement="left">                                                    
   <a class="btn btn-default bajar_posicion_elemento" title="Bajar 
 posición">
<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
</a>
</span>
<!-- SUBIR POSICIÓN -->
<span data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn-group label-tooltip" data-original- 
title="Subir posición" data-html="true" data-placement="left">                                                    
<a class="btn btn- 
default subir_posicion_elemento" title="Subir posición">
<i class="material- 
icons">arrow_drop_up</i>
 </a>
</span> 
 </span>
 </td>
```

### I need to do this:

- If a td is the first, it's subir_posicion_elemento has to be hidden.
- If a td is the last, it's bajar_posicion_elemento has to be hidden.

I don't know how to do this, I tried with CSS but can't make it work.

Thanks for your time.

### EDIT

Image showing the icons I need to hide:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAY5v.png)

### EDIT2

Ok, I finally figured it out, so here's the answer, simple but I don't have idea about css >.<

### CSS:

```
tr:first-child .subir_posicion_elemento, tr:last-child .bajar_posicion_elemento {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: do you have any live link for this website?

Comment: I dont, I added an image showing the icons I need to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS code to hide first-child and last-child icons in a table:

```
 table tr td:first-child .subir_posicion_elemento{ 
        display:none;
    }
    table tr td:last-child .bajar_posicion_elemento { 
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: Just added a similar answer, but thanks a lot because it works too! Marked yours as the good one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally figured it out, so here's the answer, simple but I don't have idea about css >.<

### CSS:

```
tr:first-child .subir_posicion_elemento, tr:last-child .bajar_posicion_elemento {
display:none;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) .subir_posicion_elemento {
 visibility:hidden; 
}
table tbody tr td:nth-last-child(1) .bajar_posicion_elemento {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

https://codepen.io/vommbat/pen/yqEBPd